# Error al guardar datos rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Les comento mi problema, al generar registros usando un `callback` ( ya lo probé pasándolos directo pero no sirve tampoco) siempre me crea el registro con un id siguiente al de este.

asociacion: `has_many :modelo_hijo`

```
self.modelo_hijo.destroy_all #elimino todas las referencias
unless self.modelo_hijo.nil? #valido que tenga ids
  self.modelo_hijo.each do |id| 
    self.modelo_hijo.create(person_id: id) #creo el incidente
  end
end
```

digamos que el id del modelo padre es 1 pero siempre al llamar `self.modelo_hijo.create(person_id: id)` me agrega el id del padre como 2 y se bloquea la transacción.

la db es mysql, rails 5.0.2 y ruby 2.2.6p396

Comment: ¿y has verificado que el efectivamente el valor de los ids dentro de la iteracion `.each` no hay algún 2? me refiero haciendo un `puts` de los valores o creando un breakpoint ¿hay algún callback en modelo_hijo que pueda estar cambiando el valor antes de crearse? Con la información que entregas en realidad no veo mucho más en lo que se te pueda ayudar.

Comment: efectivamente, me llega digamos id = 1 en la consola pero al guardar me lo ejecuta como 2 y se queda pegado